# How are Azure ASE front ends themselves load balanced?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm researching Azure App Services and App Service Environments. I can see that the "front end" acts as a load balancer for the workers. I can also see that there is a default number of 2 front ends, with more being added as the number of workers increase.

My question is, if the front ends act as a load balancer for the workers, what is deciding which of the multiple front ends serves a request? I'd always assumed a load balancer would need to be single instance or you'd end up with the same problem that was set out to solve.

As a follow up question, I'm also curious how the load is balanced to the workers? Is it simple round robin?

Answer (score 0):

The front end is a layer seven-load balancer, acting as a proxy, distributing incoming HTTP requests between different applications and their respective Workers. Currently, the App Service load-balancing algorithm is a simple round robin between a set of servers allocated for a given application.

refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt793270.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yea, I understand the load balance between the front end and the workers. My question is regarding the balancing from the http client and the multiple front end instances.